# Automatically send emails when tasks are assigned in jbpm

Tags: jbpm

I want to send an email when a task is assigned to an user in jbpm6. Please explain me how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

UserInfo can be used to figure out email addresses for users and groups, which can send email notifications.  UserInfo can be set using InternalTaskService interface.  Some examples can be found here: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.jbpm.task.service.SendIcal

You could also use a generic Task listener at the task service to respond to events whatever way you want to.

Comment: Thanks. I am very new to jbpm. Do we have to setup jbpm to send mails? eg: mail.smtp.host and etc. Or just using UserInfo is enough?

Comment: `UserInfo` is to get Email address only. Then you need to setup SMTP and etc. Check link provided above.

Comment: Thanks in advance. Please correct me if I am wrong. I am not familiar with jbpm. org.jbpm.task.service.SendIcal is not available in jbpm 6. I couldn't find it.